# delete function using inner join query builder symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig, dql

I'm new to **symfony2** stuck in some part , I have a record existing in 2 tables with `id` number, I need to delete the record in two tables using delete function

I tried with query builder, it's deleting perfectly in one table but I need to join another table also with that delete function.

My controller

```
 public function deleteAction(Request $request){
    $deleteQuery = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder('d')
    ->delete('TcPlayerBundle:TcTracks', 'd','TcprofileBundle:TcWall','t')
    ->where('d.id = ' . $request->get('id'))
    ->innerJoin('t.id=' . $request->get('id'))
    ->getQuery();
    $deleted = $deleteQuery->getResult();

    $deleted->flush();
    return $this->render('TcPlayerBundle:Default:all.html.twig',array(
            'tracks' => $tracks
    ));
}
```

The `id` in another table is `related_id`

Comment: Do `TcTracks` and `TcWall` have a relationship? (`@ORM\OneToOne` if using annotations in the entities)

Answer (score 0):

try using inner join where `d.wall` is the `TcTracks` relationship

```
$deleteQuery = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->delete('TcPlayerBundle:TcTracks', 'd',)
        ->innerJoin('d.wall', 'w', 'WITH', 'w.id = :wId')
        ->where('d.id = :dId')
        ->setParameter('wId',  $request->get('id'))
        ->setParameter('dId',  $request->get('id'))
        ->getQuery();

$deleted = $deleteQuery->getResult();

$deleted->flush();
return $this->render('TcPlayerBundle:Default:all.html.twig',array(
        'tracks' => $tracks
));
```